# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 6, 216, 1), found shape=(None, 216, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, tensorflow2.0

I'm new to TensorFlow and am stuck at a bug which is related to the shapes of the tensors.

I'm trying to create a CNN model for speech emotion classifier but I am getting an error at the `model.fit` stage.

The following are the shapes of the tensors being used:
`x_testcnn shape: (9, 216, 1) y_test shape: (9, 4)`

The model.fit code:
`cnnhistory = model.fit(x_traincnn, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=700, validation_data=(x_testcnn, y_test))`

The following is the full error I'm getting:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-bd5fc6744319> in <module>
----> 1 cnnhistory = model.fit(x_traincnn, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=700, validation_data=(x_testcnn, y_test))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1023, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 295, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 6, 216, 1), found shape=(None, 216, 1)
```

I've tried adjusting the batch sizes but I'm pretty sure I've been doing something wrong. I keep getting the error which says `cannot reshape array of size X into shape of Y` which I understand.

I checked and tried the solutions provided to similar questions on StackOverflow but they didn't quite help me get the right solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please check the dataset shape which you mentioned while defining the model and provided while model training is different. Please provide minimal reproducible code to replicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

Changing batch sizes won't help here as the error points us to check the shapes of the inputs defined.

> expected shape=(None, 6, 216, 1), found shape=(None, 216, 1)

From the error mentioned, you are getting error as you have rightly mentioned at this line :

```
cnnhistory = model.fit(x_traincnn, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=700, validation_data=(x_testcnn, y_test))
```

Hence the shape (4D) of `x_testcnn` needs to be defined as :

```
x_testcnn = x_testcnn.reshape(1,9, 216, 1) 

y_test shape: (9, 4)
```

Then use them into the `model.fit` .